# SharePoint 2016 and Workflow manager same sQL server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, workflow-foundation

I got a task to define various SharePoint farm topologies.
But I haven't any experience about SharePoint and anything else like that.
I found some information about the system requirement and the supported topologies, but I´m not sure if they are really supported.

It's hard to find helpful information. So my question.
I define a three tier topologie.

1. SharePoint 2016 Server
2. MSSQL 2016 Server
3. Workflow Manager Server

Is it supported to share the Database Server with the SharePoint and the Workflow Manager Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same SQL server for the workflow and SharePoint databases without a problem.

In fact I have a site that runs workflow manger from the SQL Server, database and IIS. This was due to the fact the all servers in the farm were Server 2016 and workflow manger is not supported on Server 2016. The only server available to install workflow manager was the SQL server which was Server 2012 R2.

Unless you have an insane amount of workflows, I wouldn't both with a dedicated workflow server, I would split the SharePoint server out into a Web and App Server.

Answer (score 0):

NO, Based on Microsoft best practices SQL server should has its own box, SP and WFM should not be located on the same server to reduce any possible dependency in the future.

ex. sometimes, you will need to renew the certs which are expired. to do so, you need to change the time back.
if SQL and SP sharing the same box, the sites and db transactions will be infected.

another example: if WFM caused any memory leak or throttling, then the SP and SQL will also be infected.

you should dedicate a box for each platform.

1 more thing, the WFM should has odd number of servers. as the Windows/ service fabric uses voting to decide which server to handle the traffic. odd number of servers will allow one of the servers to be identified as preferred server to do so.